# .htaccess that redirects all subpages to their root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got multiple domains that have been redirected to a specific subpage.

Example:
domain1.com -> domain.com/1
domain2.com -> domain.com/2

The problem is that it exists lots of links like this: domain1.com/test. With the 301 redirect now the result is the following domain.com/1test aka a 404.

How do I write a .htaccess file on my existing server that makes the domain1.com/test go to domain.com/1 on default. It's 1000 of links, so it need to be done by default.

Thanks to anyone who can help! :)

Comment: Anyone else care to try and help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following rewriteRule in your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/1 [R=301,L]
```

should be your way to archive this.

Comment: But if I don't have any server connected to the domain1.com, isn't it possible to do something on the server that the domain1.com redirects to?

Comment: I just add this to the .htaccess file on my server on domain.com?